# Apache Rewrite rule with Laravel not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel, mod-rewrite

I have the following directory structure:

```
/home/username/public_html
        my_laravel_app/
            .htaccess
            app/
            bootstrap/
            public/
                .htaccess
                index.php
                robots.txt
                ...etc (standard Laravel 4 public folder contents)
            vendor/
            ...etc (standard Laravel 4 files and folders)
```

I am trying to use an apache RewriteRule to redirect a request to `http://example.com/~user/my_laravel_app` to `http://example.com/~user/my_laravel_app/public/index.php`. In the first `.htaccess` file (the one directly under the `my_laravel_app/` directory, I have the following code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /~username/my_laravel_app
        RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !public/
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/index.php [R]
</IfModule>
```

When I navigate my browser to `http://example.com/~username/my_laravel_app`, I correctly get redirected to `http://example.com/~user/my_laravel_app/public/index.php`, and the laravel application loads as expected displaying the route for `/` as defined in `app/routes.php`.

However, I want the redirect to be internal, meaning, I don't want the users browser to display the new location. So, I simply remove the `[R]` flag on the rule. The `.htaccess` file now contains:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /~username/my_laravel_app
        RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !public/
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/index.php
</IfModule>
```

Now, when I direct the browser to `http://example.com/~username/my_laravel_app` I get a Laravel whoops error page saying there was a `NotFoundHttpException`. When I look at the error page, it seems as though the redirect is "working", because I see that the `SCRIPT_NAME` is `/~username/my_laravel_app/public/index.php`.

However, I believe the issue is possibly that the `REQUEST_URI` is `/~username/my_laravel_app/`, instead of '/', as it would be if Laravel were installed in the root of a domain like normal. So it seems as though Laravel is looking for a route match using this `REQUEST_URI` variable.

Is there any way to get Laravel to recognize the correct route?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on Laravel 4.1, and appears related to my apache config, however, I did find a workaround which was to add the following to the top of the public/index.php:

$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] = 'path/to/laravel/index.php';

// note: this is a workaround for mod_rewrite and laravel which updates the script_name from /path/to/laravel/public/index.php to /path/to/laravel/index.php. I forget exactly why this worked, but I think when I traced the problem back it was related to something in a symfony dependency.

Comment: For the record, I do not like this workaround since it is hardcoded and will fail if the environment changes. Hopefully someone has a better solution.

Comment: I suppose adding the following to bootstrap/start.php is slightly better than above but still not great:  

$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] = str_replace('/public', '', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);